# SQL merge tables by columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge

I find a way to merge tables having some columns in common and generate a new table(or update the existing table).

My version of PostgreSQL is 9.2.24

I start from an already solved post here: [Merging two tables by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411628/merging-two-tables-by-column)

In this post, we have two tables:

**Requested_Products**

```
+---------+-----------+--------------+---------+
| orderId | productId | productDesc  | prodQty |
+---------+-----------+--------------+---------+
| order1  | product1  | description1 |       1 |
| order2  | product2  | description2 |       2 |
| order2  | product3  | description3 |       5 |
| order2  | product4  | description4 |       6 |
+---------+-----------+--------------+---------+
```

and **Used_Materials**

```
+---------+------------+--------------+--------+
| orderId | materialId | materialDesc | matQty |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------+
| order1  | material1  | description4 |      3 |
| order1  | material2  | description5 |      6 |
| order1  | material3  | description6 |      2 |
| order2  | material4  | description7 |      8 |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------+
```

and we get a method to merge two tables by one column, that's **orderId**.

## New scenario

Now, imagine you have a new scenario, with new tables with some changes. We call the first one **Requested_Products_NEW**

**SQL query**

```sql
CREATE TABLE Requested_Products_NEW (
 rowID      numeric,
 CustumerID VARCHAR(128),
 year       numeric,
 productId  VARCHAR(128),
 prodQty    numeric
);

INSERT INTO Requested_Products_NEW 
VALUES
(1, 'c_1', 2017, 'product1', 1),
(2, 'c_1', 2018, 'product1', 2),
(3, 'c_1', 2017, 'product2', 5),
(4, 'c_1', 2018, 'product2', 5),
(5, 'c_2', 2017, 'product1', 6),
(6, 'c_2', 2018, 'product1', 6),
(7, 'c_2', 2017, 'product2', 6),
(8, 'c_2', 2018, 'product2', 6);
```

to get table **Requested_Products_NEW**

```
+-------+------------+------+-----------+---------+
| rowID | CustumerID | year | productId | prodQty |
+-------+------------+------+-----------+---------+
|     1 | c_1        | 2017 | product1  |       1 |
|     2 | c_1        | 2018 | product1  |       2 |
|     3 | c_1        | 2017 | product2  |       5 |
|     4 | c_1        | 2018 | product2  |       5 |
|     5 | c_2        | 2017 | product1  |       6 |
|     6 | c_2        | 2018 | product1  |       6 |
|     7 | c_2        | 2017 | product2  |       6 |
|     8 | c_2        | 2018 | product2  |       6 |
+-------+------------+------+-----------+---------+
```

We can see in **Requested_Products_NEW**  that each row is unique identified by the combination of three columns, **CustumerID**, **year**, **productId**.

Now imagine I have new information about these rows. Imagine I have a new table having the same three columns that identify each row. We call this table **Product_satisfation**.

**SQL query**

```sql
CREATE TABLE Product_satisfation(
 rowID      numeric,
 CustumerID VARCHAR(128),
 year       numeric,
 productId  VARCHAR(128),
 Satisfation    numeric
);

INSERT INTO Product_satisfation
VALUES
(1, 'c_1', 2017, 'product1', 8),
(2, 'c_1', 2018, 'product1', 2),
(3, 'c_1', 2017, 'product2', 1),
(4, 'c_2', 2017, 'product1', 5),
(5, 'c_2', 2018, 'product1', 7),
(6, 'c_2', 2017, 'product2', 2),
(7, 'c_2', 2018, 'product2', 8),
(8, 'c_2', 2014, 'product2', 4),
(9, 'c_1', 2020, 'product1', 9);
```

to get this table **Product_satisfation**

```
+-------+------------+------+-----------+-------------+
| rowID | CustumerID | year | productId | Satisfation |
+-------+------------+------+-----------+-------------+
|     1 | c_1        | 2017 | product1  |           8 |
|     2 | c_1        | 2018 | product1  |           2 |
|     3 | c_1        | 2017 | product2  |           1 |
|     4 | c_2        | 2017 | product1  |           5 |
|     5 | c_2        | 2018 | product1  |           7 |
|     6 | c_2        | 2017 | product2  |           2 |
|     7 | c_2        | 2018 | product2  |           8 |
|     8 | c_2        | 2014 | product2  |           4 |
|     9 | c_1        | 2020 | product1  |           9 |
+-------+------------+------+-----------+-------------+
```

How you can see, in the last table I have some information about satisfaction related to first table, but, not all rows match with the first table. For example, the first row of **Product_satisfation** (rowID=1) match with the first row of **Requested_Products_NEW** (rowID=1), because the CustumerID, the year and the productID is the same ( c_1, 2017, product1).
But the fourth row (rowID=4) of **Requested_Products_NEW** (c_1, 2018, product2) has no match on **Product_satisfation**. In natural language, we do not have any information about the satisfaction of customer2 for product2 bought in 2018.

The same thing can happen in the opposite sense. For example, we have information about the satisfaction of custumer2 for product2 bought in 2014 and for custumer1 for product1 bought in 2020, but for these years, costumers and products, we do not have "quantity information" ("quantity info" is in the first table **Requested_Products_NEW**). In other words, we cannot match the information of rowID 7 and rowID 8 of the table **Product_satisfation** with the table **Requested_Products_NEW**.

And in this context, **I want to merge these tables into one table** in order to get all information coming from these two tables. I need this in one table for some regression analysis. If possible, I prefer to update an existing table (for example, **Requested_Products_NEW**) with new columns and rows that are the results of the merging step.

Here the expected output, which is a table containing 10 rows. I remove rowID beacause is not pertinent there (I added rowID here to explain my purpose, but I do not really have this column in my data):

```
+------------+------+-----------+---------+-------------+
| CustumerID | year | productId | prodQty | Satisfation |
+------------+------+-----------+---------+-------------+
| c_1        | 2017 | product1  | 1       | 8           |
| c_1        | 2018 | product1  | 2       | 2           |
| c_1        | 2017 | product2  | 5       | 1           |
| c_1        | 2018 | product2  | 5       | null        |
| c_2        | 2017 | product1  | 6       | 5           |
| c_2        | 2018 | product1  | 6       | 7           |
| c_2        | 2017 | product2  | 6       | 2           |
| c_2        | 2018 | product2  | 6       | 8           |
| c_2        | 2014 | product2  | null    | 4           |
| c_1        | 2020 | product1  | null    | 9           |
+------------+------+-----------+---------+-------------+
```

I appreciate all you help! Thank you to you all guys!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: I know, I have to update it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a `full join`:

```
select *
from product_satisfaction ps full join
     Requested_Products_NEW rp
     using (customer_id, product_id, year)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. 
I've tried a FULL OUTER JOIN before and I had some issues The full join seems to be more appropriate and it's probably what I need. 

But, I still have a problem. I have 90 variables to merge in one table. But, at some point, my table became very large, 10 times greater then what it should be. I thought it was my outer join the problem, but finally, it's possible I have a problem in my data model, probably some duplicates. But I still do not understand how some duplicates can push to have millions of rowsinstead of 700 or 800 hundred thousand. Thank you a lot

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff, you help me to point out on my real problem. I had about 20-30 duplicates in my model data which caused millions of duplicates when full join was applied! Now everything is ok, and the full join is what I need. Thank you a lot